# Conditional statement in express router after find and populate info

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have a route like this:

```
// Logged in users modules (Users view)
router.get('/user', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
Module.find()
    .populate('user')
    // Check if user.level >= module.minLevel

    .then(modules => {
        res.render('modules/user', {
            modules: modules
        });
    });
});
```

I know the value of user.level and module.minLevel and I want to render only the modules for the condition: if user.level >= module.minLevel

**It's possible to wrap the block
.then(modules)....
inside one If? How on this case? 
Or another solution?**

Note: using mongoose and mLab as database

Comment: Is `Module` MongooseJs?

Comment: yes, Mongoose.js